# To open an EXE on a remote computer using ip address

Tags: c#

I want to open a program on a remote computer whose IP is 10.64.4.38
through c# windows based program.

The file that I want to open is on .
@"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe"

I am using following code but it's not working. please help me out

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();

options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; 
options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Default; 
options.Username = userName; 
options.Password = password; 
options.Authority = null; 
options.EnablePrivileges = true;
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options); 
scope.Connect();

// Create the process 
using (ManagementClass process = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process")) 
{
    ConnectionOptions conn = new ConnectionOptions();

    conn.Username = "support";
    conn.Password = "password";
    process.Scope = scope; 
    process.InvokeMethod("Create", commandLine); 
    ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(@"\\10.64.4.38\root\cimv2", conn);
    Process g = Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe");
```

Comment: Be patient, some of us have jobs to do.. and I was writing and tidying my code for it to look nice.. 4 minute wait is hardly a wait

Answer (score 0):

This is an excerpt from a program I wrote which does what you're trying to do.  You used Process g = .. this creates a local process. this is not what you wanted.

```
 ConnectionOptions connOptions = new ConnectionOptions();
  connOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
  connOptions.EnablePrivileges = true;
  ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(String.Format(@"\\{0}\ROOT\CIMV2", remoteMachine),
 connOptions);
  manScope.Connect();
  ObjectGetOptions objectGetOptions = new ObjectGetOptions();
  ManagementPath managementPath = new ManagementPath("Win32_Process");
  ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass(manScope, managementPath, objectGetOptions);
  ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
  Console.WriteLine("{0}>Remoteexec: {1}",remoteMachine, sBatFile);
  inParams["CommandLine"] = sBatFile;
  inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = !nocopy?@"c:\656":@"c:\"; // this is part of my current process so this needs to be the remote folder you wish to work from, so c:\656 is just a default
  ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, null);
  UInt32 rv = (UInt32) outParams["returnValue"];
  uint ProcessId = (uint) outParams["processId"];

  String result = "";
  switch (rv)
  {
case 0:
 result = "ok";
 break;
case 2:
 result = "Access denied";
 break;
case 3:
 result = "Insufficient privilage";
 break;
case 8:
 result = "Unknown failure";
 break;
case 9:
 result = "Path not found";
 break;
case 21:
 result = "Unknown failure";
 break;
default:
 result = "Mega bad";
 break;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("{0}>Creation of the process returned: {1}",remoteMachine,result);
```

This will also then tell you why the remote process failed.. if it fails to launch

Comment: i have sent the IP address and also user name and password please send me with that ip and password.i did not get your code.because i am a little new in c#.

Comment: but its showing error with remotemachine and sbatfile

Comment: {1}",remoteMachine, sBatFile);
  inParams["CommandLine"] = sBatFile;
  inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = !nocopy?@"

Comment: its underlining these three word
remoteMachine    sBatFile  and nocopy

Comment: @abid If its underlining these words, simple mouse over should write out error. These variables are probably not defined. You should be able to figure this out by yourself, and not expect somebody else to write a whole program for you. These are just basic errors. Maybe you should try some tutorials or read the documentation before trying to solve more complex problems.

Comment: remotemachine.. well what do you think that is? sbatfile - ok, so that isnt obvious but as it goes to "commandline" what do you think that could be?? the nocopy - I did make a comment against that.. thats just picking which folder it runs from - as per my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using this line?

```
Process g = Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe");
```

All this will do is try to start the process **locally**.

Instead initialize MagemementClass like so (where server is the path to your WMI enabled computer):

```
process = new ManagementClass(@"\\server\root\cimv2:Win32_Process");
```

And then invoke the method:

```
object[] theProcessToRun = { @"C:\\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe" };

process.InvokeMethod("Create", theProcessToRun);
```

Comment: can you give me the whole code please its showing error .boss please help me with new easy code